# Android - Snackbar - allow to be dismissed any horizontal direction

Tags: android, android-snackbar

We are using Snackbar in our application. However it can be dismissed by default when swiped off to the right. Is there a setting which makes it dismissable when swiped any horizontal direction (meaning swiping it off left or right direction) - to make it easier for left handed people as well.

Answer (score 0):

The point of this behavior, is that it will behave the same way on all Android phones. That also means users familiar with the Android experience, or even those who have seen the Snackbar and dismissed it before will know that swiping to the right is going to dismiss it.

There's a request to change this behavior, and it might be approved with enough stars (it's currently on Medium priority): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80102

Answer (score 0):

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(fab, "snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
            final Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
            snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            snackbar.show();
            snackbarLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = snackbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    if (lp instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
                        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) lp).setBehavior(new SwipeDismissBehavior<Snackbar.SnackbarLayout>(){
                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipeDismissView(View view) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        snackbarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        snackbarLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        snackbarLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
```

This code worked for me.

Comment: This piece of code does not work unless you edit "canSwipeDismissView" to "return true;" also it breaks callbacks on dismissed event.